# XSL Style Sheet no longer working for Excel

Tags: xml, excel, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm a librarian trying to perform a collection analysis by translating our records from a widely used platform into Excel. I had received some help before with the XSL Style sheet that worked for months.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <record>
            <xsl:for-each select="//catalog">
                <itemline>
                    <callNumber>
                        <xsl:value-of select="call/callNumber" />
                    </callNumber>
                    <title>
                        <xsl:value-of select="marc/marcEntry[@label='Title']" />
                    </title>
                    <yearOfPublication>
                        <xsl:value-of select="yearOfPublication" />
                    </yearOfPublication>
                    <xsl:for-each select="call/item/totalCheckouts">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <dateLastUsed>
                        <xsl:value-of select="call/item/dateLastUsed" />
                    </dateLastUsed>
                    <location>
                        <xsl:value-of select="call/item/location" />
                    </location>
                </itemline>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </record>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Suddenly this code no longer works with new reports generated by the system. I want it to return all of the information on a  record onto one row in Excel, but now it puts each piece of information on a new row, making it impossible to manipulate the data.

Here is an example of an old record:

```
<catalog>
    <flexibleKey>l55041415</flexibleKey>
    <numberOfTitleHolds>0</numberOfTitleHolds>
    <totalHolds>0</totalHolds>
    <numberOfCallNumbers>1</numberOfCallNumbers>
    <bibliographicLevel>FULL</bibliographicLevel>
    <catalogFormat>MARC</catalogFormat>
    <createdBy>TECH</createdBy>
    <dateCreated>2009-11-09</dateCreated>
    <dateCataloged>2009-01-29</dateCataloged>
    <modifiedBy>TECH</modifiedBy>
    <dateModified>2009-11-12</dateModified>
    <catalogKey>129825</catalogKey>
    <yearOfPublication>1953</yearOfPublication>
    <marc>
        <marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="1 ">Colonius, Lillian.</marcEntry>
        <marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">At the bakery / by Lillian Colonius and Glenn W. Schroeder.</marcEntry>
        <marcEntry tag="260" label="Publication info" ind="  ">Los Angeles, CA : Melmont Pub., Inc., c1953.</marcEntry>
        <marcEntry tag="300" label="Physical description" ind="  ">24 p. : ill. ; 24 cm.</marcEntry>
        <marcEntry tag="650" label="Subject term" ind=" 1">Bread.</marcEntry>
    </marc>
    <call>
        <callNumber>PZ 10.C694 ATG 1958</callNumber>
        <library>UOG-RFK</library>
        <item>
            <numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
            <numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
            <numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
            <totalCharges>0</totalCharges>
            <inhouseCharges>1</inhouseCharges>
            <totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
            <totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
            <intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
            <intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
            <intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
            <recirculate>YES</recirculate>
            <dateLastUsed>2017-02-17</dateLastUsed>
            <isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
            <copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
            <itemID>33296000201835</itemID>
            <library>UOG-RFK</library>
            <libraryDescription>University of Guam - RFK Memorial Library</libraryDescription>
            <location>JUVENILE</location>
            <homeLocation>JUVENILE</homeLocation>
            <price currency="$">30.00</price>
            <category1>JUVENILE</category1>
            <type>JUVENILE</type>
            <numberOfPieces>1</numberOfPieces>
            <dateCreated>2009-11-09</dateCreated>
            <isPermanent>true</isPermanent>
        </item>
    </call>
</catalog>
```

And here is an example of a new record:

```
<catalog>
    <catalogKey>59433</catalogKey>
    <yearOfPublication>1999</yearOfPublication>
    <marc>
        <marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="1 ">Rose, Ed (Edwin)</marcEntry>
        <marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">50 ways to teach your learner : activities and interventions for building high-performance teams / by Ed Rose with Steve Buckley.</marcEntry>
        <marcEntry tag="260" label="Publication info" ind="  ">San Francisco, CA : Jossey-Bass, c1999.</marcEntry>
        <marcEntry tag="300" label="Physical description" ind="  ">xvii, 264 p. : ill. ; 28 cm.</marcEntry>
        <marcEntry tag="650" label="Subject term" ind=" 0">Teams in the workplace--Training of.</marcEntry>
        <marcEntry tag="650" label="Subject term" ind=" 0">Experiential learning.</marcEntry>
        <marcEntry tag="700" label="Added Entry-Personal Name" ind="10">Buckley, Steve, 1960-</marcEntry>
    </marc>
    <call>
        <callNumber>HD 66 .R65 1999</callNumber>
        <library>UOG-RFK</library>
        <item>
            <numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
            <numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
            <numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
            <totalCharges>3</totalCharges>
            <inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
            <totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
            <totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
            <intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
            <intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
            <intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
            <recirculate>YES</recirculate>
            <dateLastUsed>2003-12-17</dateLastUsed>
            <isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
            <copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
            <itemID>33296001664171</itemID>
            <library>UOG-RFK</library>
            <libraryDescription>University of Guam - RFK Memorial Library</libraryDescription>
            <location>MAIN</location>
            <homeLocation>MAIN</homeLocation>
            <price currency="$">42.00</price>
            <category1>MAIN</category1>
            <type>BOOK</type>
            <numberOfPieces>1</numberOfPieces>
            <dateCreated>2002-05-22</dateCreated>
            <isPermanent>true</isPermanent>
        </item>
    </call>
</catalog>
```

I don't see any major changes to the structure of the records that would cause this change and don't know XSLT well enough to even start to trouble shoot it.

Comment: Can you share the difference in the outputs and the desired output?

Comment: I am not convinced the issue is with XSLT. How is the XML it generates actually imported into Excel?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to replicate the problem.  The two input records you show produce output with identical structure (within limits), as indeed any input must:  the outer structure of the output is hard-coded in your stylesheet and the only variations in the output will be data values and the number of `totalCheckouts` elements.

The two input records differ only in that the 'new' one omits the first eleven children of the `catalog` element.  Since none of those is copied into the output by the stylesheet, you are utterly correct to surmise that this difference should not be responsible for any change in the output of the stylesheet.

If the results have changed in Excel, then the most likely cause is that the import process has changed somehow; if it's done by hand, it's easy to imagine someone finding different ways to import the XML data into Excel which have different results.  If the import process is automated, then I'd ask whether the copy of Excel used has changed at all:  has it been upgraded, has someone changed a configuration option, ...?  If neither the spreadsheet software nor the method of importing the output from your XSLT has changed, then you might want to look again to ensure that the samples you've given are in fact what you have taken them to be.  Can you replicate the different behaviors using these samples?